# Безопасность программы на python

Tags: python, postgresql, безопасность, pyside6

Пишу программу на python + pyside6 + postgres для производства. Программа представляет собой удобную панель для радактирования нужных таблиц в бд. Есть личный кабинет, без авторизации в котором работа в программе не возможна. Пароли юзеров хранятся в md5. Пароль для бд в сыром виде, но находится в коде скомпилированной в exe программы.
Саму программу ещё не релизил на производстве так как хочу уточнить вопросы с безопасностью.
В python пришёл около года назад.

Вопросы:
1)Опасно ли хранить пароли в скомпилировнной программе(exe) и возможно ли злоумышленнику их получить, например от бд ?
2) Как защитить программу, если это возможно и какими способами(если можно, ссылку на материал)

Comment: 1) Если злоумышленник получит ваш exe, то ничто не помешает ему его декомпилировать; 2) Для начала определитесь, от кого/чего вы хотите защититься

Comment: Можно скомпилировать в С через специальный компилятор. Можно обфусцировать код. Можно понадеяться, что злоумышленник не сможет декомпилировать питон 3.12 версии из байт кода‍♀️  Но тут сходу вспоминается анекдот о неуловимом Джо.

Comment: @Amgarak но ничто из перечисленного не помешает вытащить пароль прямо из оперативки, напримвр

Comment: Пароли должны храниться в отдельном хранилище, не доступным пользователю (напр в удалённой БД). Храниться в зашифрованном виде. И почитай про соль.

Comment: @andreymal вытащили мы хеш пароля, а что дальше с ним делать?

Comment: @Amgarak какой ещё хеш, для подключения к базе нужен открытый пароль, он и будет лежать открытым в оперативке

Comment: а нет ли способа указать бд, что бы она принимала пароль на подключение именно в хеш ? Спасибо большое за акивное комментирование. Я черпаю опыт с каждого слова.

Comment: @MEXANIZM100 ну тогда злоумышленник вытащит хеш пароля и подключится к базе с помощью хеша пароля, какая разница-то

Comment: Да, логично, затупил )

Comment: Получается нет ни единого с90 процентного способа защитить программу ? А если шифровать пароль а в программе его дешифровать ? Логично, что взломщик может накопать функцию дешифровки и прочитать код. Это так ?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Python 3.11 не декомпилируется на данный момент.</s>Python 3.11 и 3.12 уже декомпилируюся. Но и ехе распаковать и пропатчить можно без особых проблем. Обфускация и шифрование не спасёт от патча.

Единственное верное решение - не хранить пароли вместе с приложением.

Используйте windows credential store например. Администратор вводит пароль при первом запуске.

Comment: Не знаю насколько 3.11 не декомпилируется, сам не проверял, но на гитхабе видел несколько тем где предлагалось решение для данного вопроса. Правда в комментариях не у всех получалось получить чтото вменяемое.